# How to check if all parameters are false in PHP?

Tags: php

I was trying to return when all variables are false. How can I do that? I can only change `&&` or `||` operator.

Here is my code :

```
$a = false;
$b = false;
$c = 1; // $c could be 1 to 4

// only get in this condition when any of the variable is false
if( (!$a || !$b) && $c <= 2)
{
  return 'exit';
}
```

Comment: After reading this `you can only change && or || operator.`. If it is asked in any exam, then please do it your self first., You have not shared your  tried.

Comment: if i understand you right this should work if( !$a && !$b && !$c)

Comment: Answer of this quiz is  `if( (!$a && !$b) || $c)` , [Check live demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ee6e1f5057b0780ebc930c6f419d4dddbfc43ac7) @Mohib: It would be great if you solve this and come with other tried code.

Comment: @RishiRaut i update the description have a look

Comment: Although I have given answer in above comment, Please tell us why you `can only change && or || operator` ?

Comment: because this a logical error from my big project $a,$b,$c is only use to replicate the problem.actually variables are more complex then that

Comment: After saying this you made more confusion `this will not work if $a = true; $b = true; $c = false`